# Membership via transitive closure

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory

I would like to find a condition which is both necessary and sufficient to $x\in y$, using only $=$, $\cup$, $\cap$, $\emptyset$, and the transitive closure operator.

(A little bit of context may help: I am trying to give a categorical interpretation to the membership relation, given that I have managed to interpret all other operations above.)

My question is: is this even possible? I suspect it might not be, but I have no clue as to how to find a proof of this.

Edit. There is no power-object in said category, which makes it a whole lot harder.

Comment: You might find helpful [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404974900322/pdf?md5=fc21e5f6a11ac77d0e5620cba7ac4ce0&pid=1-s2.0-0022404974900322-main.pdf).

Comment: @Rick thank you! This is actually close to what I'm doing, but it relies heavily on power-objects, while I don't have them in my category (actually, that's the whole point in using transitive closures here).

Comment: What characterises the transitive closure? If we cannot use $\in$, then how do you express that something is the transitive closure of $x$?

Comment: @MarkKamsma using the meta-theory. The point is: usually we take $\in$ to be "primitive" and the transitive closure to be derived from that and other primitive concepts; is it possible to do it back-wards? Taking the transitive closure to be primitive, and from that (and other primitives such as $\cup$, $\emptyset$, ...) define/interpret $\in$.

Comment: $\in$ is a binary relation, but $\cup$, $\cap$, $\emptyset$, and $\operatorname{tcl}$ are functions. Do you mean to allow $=$ as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I should have said I have equality, too.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that it can't be done, but I don't have a counterexample. Using $\cap$ and $=$ (or $\cup$ and $=$) you can define $\subseteq$, and it's certainly true that $x \in y$ implies $x \subseteq \operatorname{tcl} y$, but that implication cannot be reversed.

Comment: That's where I got, but I don't even know where to start looking for a proof that this has to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to define $x \in y$ using only $=$, $\cap$, $\cup$, $\operatorname{tcl}$, and $\varnothing$.

Indeed, if it were possible, then it would certainly be possible to do so when $x = \varnothing$ and $y$ is a non-transitive set. But $\{ \varnothing, y, \operatorname{tcl} y \}$ is already closed under the operations $\cap$, $\cup$, $\operatorname{tcl}$, and $\varnothing$, and since the only binary relation we have available is $=$, any binary relation definable in this language cannot depend on what $y$ actually is. But there are non-transitive sets $y$ where $\varnothing \in y$ and also non-transitive sets $y$ where  $\varnothing \not\in y$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!